# sort key does not seem to count utf8 characters correctly

Tags: sorting

I want to sort the lines of the following (minimal example) file `tmp.txt` by position 3 and 4 (my original file has various number of spaces, so I cannot use that).

```
o Aa
á Ab
è Ba
f Bb
```

The encoding of the file is utf8.

```
prompt$ file -i tmp.txt
tmp.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

And my locale is also utf8

```
prompt$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Still, the output of the following command is not what I expect:

```
prompt$ cat tmp.txt | sort -R | sort --debug --key 1.3,1.4
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
á Ab
 __
____
o Aa
  __
____
è Ba
 __
____
f Bb
  __
____
```

I have turned on `--debug` to visualize what `sort` is doing. It counts the special characters as two and therefore gets the key position wrong, as indicated by the underscores. Can anybody tell me, how to convince `sort` to count special characters only as one?

```
prompt$ sort --version
sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.26
```

Best, Josef.